# Array of digit as string to simple int conversion problem

Tags: javascript, string, casting, int

Console debug shows me that array is ex. ["2"], but I need [2].

Why casting doesnt'work?

```
function filterElements(deals) {

    var result = deals,
        categories= $('#deals-categories').data('current_category');
        if (categories != undefined && categories.length > 0) {
            for (var i; i < categories.length; i++) {
                categories[i] = parseInt(categories[i]);
            }
            console.log(categories, 'cats');
                result = $.grep(result, function(e) {
                    return $.inArray(e.category_id, categories) != -1;
     });                
        }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize `var i = 0` in the loop declaration.

Full code cleanup:

```
function filterElements(deals) {

    var result = deals,
        categories = $('#deals-categories').data('current_category');

        if (categories && categories.length) {
            for (var i=0; i<categories.length; i++) {
                categories[i] = parseInt(categories[i], 10);
            }
            console.log(categories, 'cats');
            result = $.grep(result, function(e) {
                return $.inArray(e.category_id, categories) !== -1;
            });                
        }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: The only weirdness I see now is using `$.inArray()` inside of `$.grep()`.

Answer (score 0):

use `categories[i] * 1` to cast

`parseInt` works in a bit unexpected way sometimes :)

`parseInt("010")` will return 8 in some browsers, and 10 in others: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp

Comment: I think Matt Ball explains the issue, while parseInt is still not recommended when dealing with strings which are for sure ints.

Comment: @Michael why not? Ohhh, w3schools... `/facepalm`. This is why JSLint recommends that you **always specify the radix in `parseInt` calls** (until ECMAScript 5). A **much** better resource than w3schools: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: yeah, `radix` solves the issue, but requires too much letters :)

Comment: The better alternatives to `parseInt()` are `Number` or unary `+`, not `*1`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090518/string-to-int-use-parseint-or-number and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594625/parseint-alternative

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure? This is an example similar to yours:

```
var strings = ["1", "2", "3"];
var valueAsInt = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++){
   valueAsInt = parseInt(strings[i]);
   if(typeof(valueAsInt) == 'number'){
      alert('Is an integer');
   }
}
```

The message 'Is an integer' is shown three times. I think in your code the parser works, but maybe later, the value is converted to string by comparing with other string or, maybe some concatenation.