# ~~ vs parseInt?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the “double tilde” (~~) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971645/what-is-the-double-tilde-operator-in-javascript)

The D3 tutorial gives a function that produces a random sequence:

```
var t = 1297110663, // start time (seconds since epoch)
    v = 70, // start value (subscribers)
    data = d3.range(33).map(next); // starting dataset

function next() {
  return {
    time: ++t,
    value: v = ~~Math.max(10, Math.min(90, v + 10 * (Math.random() - .5)))
  };
}
```

Note the ~~ (tilda tilda) in:

```
    value: v = ~~Math.max(10, Math.min(90, v + 10 * (Math.random() - .5)))
```

From playing around in the javascript terminal, I see:

```
~~1
1
~~-1
-1
~~-1.3
-1
parseInt(5)
5
parseInt(-5)
-5
parseInt(-5.3)
-5
parseInt(5.3)
5
```

Since ~~ and parseInt seem to be equivalent, whats the rationale for using parseInt?

Comment: [Bitwise not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/operators/bitwise_operators#.7E_(Bitwise_NOT))

Comment: TIL about the tilde bitwise NOT operator in JavaScript. Thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

They are not equivalent.

- `parseInt()` turns strings into numbers, reading up to and ignoring the first non-integer character, and also possibly performing base conversion (e.g. interpreting a string as octal, or hexadecimal).

```js
console.log(



  parseInt(011)           +'\n'+ // 9
  parseInt('011')         +'\n'+ // 11
  parseInt('42 cats')     +'\n'+ // 42
  parseInt('0xcafebabe')  +'\n'+ // 3405691582
  parseInt('deadbeef',16) +'\n'+ // 3735928559
  parseInt('deadbeef',36) +'\n'  // 1049836114599



);
```

- `var x = ~~y;` is a 'trick'—similar to `var x = y << 0;`—that (ab)uses the [unary bitwise NOT operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) to force the result to be in the range of a signed 32-bit integer, discarding any non-integer portion.

```js
console.log(



  parseInt(011)                +'\n'+// 9
  parseInt('011')              +'\n'+// 11
  parseInt('42 cats')          +'\n'+// 42
  parseInt('0xcafebabe')       +'\n'+// 3405691582
  parseInt('deadbeef',16)      +'\n'+// 3735928559
  parseInt('deadbeef',36)      +'\n' // 1049836114599



);
```

Using `~~x` is often done because:

1. It's usually faster than calling a method.
2. It's faster to type than anything else.
3. It makes power users feel cool because it's sort of inscrutable and also sort of justifiable. :)

*As seen in the `cafebabe` test, numbers above 2<sup>31</sup> − 1 (2,147,483,647) or below −2<sup>31</sup>

(−2,147,483,648) will "wrap around" due to the limits of a signed 32-bit integer.*

Comment: You might want to explain exactly what `~` is. As in bitwise not.

Comment: why should parseInt('011'); yeld 9?

Comment: @DavidFregoli Because of [octal parsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_Interpretations_with_No_Radix).

Comment: parseInt('011',8); then?

Comment: @DavidFregoli If you are dead-set on using `parseInt` instead of [one of the better choices](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10184402/405017) then you should use `parseInt('011',10)` if you want the result `11`.

Comment: In modern browsers, that implement ECMAscript 5, there is no octal parsing for strings with leading zero by default, so `parseInt('011');` will return 11 in them. By older browsers like IE8 still return 9, so you have to specify explicit radix to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 9):

`parseInt` isn't limited to signed 32 bit numbers.

```
   // Top range for a bitwise operator provides a valid result
~~((Math.pow(2,32)/2)-1); // 2147483647

   // Beyond the top range provides undesired result
~~(Math.pow(2,32)/2); // -2147483648
```

Also, with `parseInt` you can specify the radix.

Comment: @gdoron They show that bitwise not clamps to 32-bit values, rolling around into signed-complement land once you hit 2^32

Answer (score 2):

```
~~"red" === 0

isNaN(parseInt("red"))
```

parseInt can handle over 32 bit numbers as well

Answer (score 1):

Simple: It the more readable and convinient variant.

The bitwise NOT operator is designed for some other use, but can be misused for truncating float values. In your example, `Math.floor` had also been possible.

Also, they don't behave similiar in many cases. `parseInt` is no limited to 32 bit, it can parse numbers represented in different positional notations and it also handles non-numeric values with `NaN`.