# Get nth value in array sum of all values

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have an array of elements, i need to add the every first, seven, thirteen and nineteen (70, 74, 50, 70) values and sum of them using java script.

```
var rowSpanHeight = ['70', '70', '70', '70', '70', '70','74', '74', '74', '74', '74', '74','50', '50', '50', '50', '50', '50','70', '70', '70', '70', '70', '70'];
```

Anyone can help? Thanks!

Comment: Are all the repeated values always consecutive ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Why dont you just use the indices and then calculate the sum?

Comment: sorry, first 6 values are same and 7, 13, 19 are diffrent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume from your question that you have to add them whenever they change in the array, in that case you can use:

```
function sumIfDifferent( inputArr ) {
    var lastNum = -1;
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0, l = inputArr.length; i < l; i++) {
        num = parseInt(inputArr[i], 10);
        if (num != lastNum) {
            lastNum = num;
            total+=num;
        }
    }
    return total;
}

alert(sumIfDifferent(['70', '70', '70', '70', '70', '70','74', '74', '74', '74', '74', '74','50', '50', '50', '50', '50', '50','70', '70', '70', '70', '70', '70']));
```

Comment: Finally someone gets the generic answer.

Comment: Avoid using parseInt without the radix parameter (10 here), or use directly a bitwise operator : `num = inputArr[i] | 0`

Answer (score 1):

Simply add them up:

```js
var rowSpanHeight = ['70', '70', '70', '70', '70', '70','74', '74', '74', '74', '74', '74','50', '50', '50', '50', '50', '50','70', '70', '70', '70', '70', '70'];
document.write(parseInt(rowSpanHeight[0]) + parseInt(rowSpanHeight[6]) + parseInt(rowSpanHeight[12]) + parseInt(rowSpanHeight[18]));
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple approach would be -

```js
  var rowSpanHeight = ['70', '70', '70', '70', '70', '70','74', '74', '74', '74', '74', '74','50', '50', '50', '50', '50', '50','70', '70', '70', '70', '70', '70'];
    var sum = ~~rowSpanHeight [0] + ~~rowSpanHeight [6] + ~~rowSpanHeight [12] + ~~rowSpanHeight [18];
    console.log(sum);
```

note: the use of `~~` (double tilde) here is a quick way to convert the string to a number, had the string been 12.12 this would not have been used as `~~` will remove everything after a decimal place (much like parseInt). more info in SO questions like https://stackoverflow.com/a/10841248/2737978

Comment: dude....... double bitwise nots for someone who doesn't understand how to access an array element by index? ;)

Comment: yep i was just going to edit it then saw someone else had already posted the same with parseInt so figured would leave it as another option

Comment: Totally kidding by the way.

Comment: nah it's what i though after i posted it and saw I started the answer with the phrase 'simple approach' :)

Answer (score 0):

something like this might work ...

```
var sum=0;
for(var a in rowSpanHeight){
    switch(a){
        case 0:
        case 6:
        case 12:
        case 18:
             sum+=parseInt(rowSpanHeight[a]);
        break;
    }
}
```